# Where to find other versions of Opera browser as deb packages?

Tags: browser, opera

I used Opera mainly for the Unite feature [now to be abandoned](http://my.opera.com/addons/blog/2012/04/24/sunsetting-unite-and-widgets).
It is missing in v. 12. Some say its features will re-emerge in future extensions etc. Until then, Unite is still accessible in v. 11. Where do I get the v.11 deb?

As opera-unite is no longer supported, it is possible that the server that provides the file sharing etc will soon be unaccessible.
Even if that is the case the question should maybe not be closed at it has a general usefulness independently of the `unite` issue.

**(It seems that in Windows upgrading from v.11 to v.12 keeps the `unite`. Not in Ubuntu, as far as I can tell.)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1164/opera_11.64.1403_i386.deb) is the x86 variant of the latest version before 12 (that is, version 11.64) at Opera's own website.  Even older versions can be found [here](http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/).

---

> **Note:** In order to use both Opera 11 *and* a later build simultaneously, one of them should be an alpha, beta, or nightly build.
>
> So, after installing version 11, the latest [bleeding-edge version][4] of Opera can be also installed and used.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://gamblis.com/2011/01/28/opera-11-01-for-ubuntu-deb-download/.